# Распаковка файла JSON в архиве zip

Tags: c#, ssis

Скачиваю файл csv сжатый в архив.

```
HttpWebResponse response_get = (HttpWebResponse)request_get.GetResponse();
```

Файл имеет расширение `zip`.

Разархивирую его

```
if (response_get.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("zip"))
{
    // Распаковка данных из формата zip
    using (Stream s = response_get.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(s))
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.Entries[0];
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
            {
                response = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

В результате получаю только заголовок `PK`

что не так?

Comment: Так файл это zip архив или content-encoding gzip? Какая именно проблема решается? `HttpWebRequest` давно устарел, используйте `HttpClient`. Что вы хотите получить в итоге?